# Insert code based on date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I understand the basics of this, but I'm trying to set up a snippet of code that would allow me to insert HTML using jQuery's '.html' or '.append' function.

I've managed this alone, but I have to insert the code based on the seasons - a little more explanation here: I need to have a certain section of code included during the summer, one for winter, spring and so on.

Now, I know how to get the current date and I know how to use IF statements but I keep getting stuck on the format of the date that would allow me to compare it to set dates for the seasons and then have the function run for each one.

In case someone needs them here are some examples, not accurate ones of course:

- Winter: January to March
- Spring: March to June
- Summer: June to November
- Autumn: November to January

If someone could give me an example of this I would be very grateful. (I also couldn't figure out how to add more specific dates for the start and end of the seasons due to the fact some months have fewer/more days .... and also for events such as Christmas and Halloween)

Comment: what date format you are messing with?

Comment: @Pilot I tried using just the day and month, so dd/mm but couldn't get it to check if that was greater than or equal to a value I set myself. Which would you recommend?

Comment: If you use strings, you should at least use the format `mmdd` because that sorts correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(),
    month = date.getMonth(),
    date = date.getDate()m
    season;


if(month <= 2 && date <= 20) { // Up to 20th March
    season = "Winter";
} else if(month <= 5 && date <= 5) { // Up to 5th June
    season = "Spring";
} // etc


$("#myDiv").html("It is " + season);
```

Updated with date example

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will have a play around with it now, can you think of a way to do more specific dates, maybe using days too?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use string dates, use the [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). It can tell you the current month which allows you to:

```
var month = new Date().getMonth();
if(month >= 0 && month <= 2) { // Jan ... March
} ...
```

Note that months start with 0 (== January) to 11 (== December)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will have a play around with it now, can you think of a way to do more specific dates, maybe using days too?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation I linked to. Date objects have lots of methods that give you the year, the day, the hour, minute and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option, a lot more complicated, but you can set the dates as requested, and check what season it.

```
var getSeason = function() {
    var self = this;
    return function(date, o) {
        if (date == 'getDefaults') return self.defaults;
        if (date == 'setDefaults') self.defaults = $.extend(self.defaults, o);

        date = typeof date == 'string' ? new Date(date) : date;
        var year   = date.getFullYear(),
            arr    = $.map(self.defaults, function(d, key) {
                    var dt = new Date(year, d.slice(0,2)-1, d.slice(3,5), 0,0,0,0);
                    dt.setDate(dt.getDate()-1); // subtract one to get the startdate right
                    return {season : key, start_date : dt};
                }).sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a.start_date.getTime() > b.start_date.getTime() ? 1 : -1;
                }),
            season = arr[arr.length-1].season;

        $.each(arr, function(idx, itm) {
            if (date > itm.start_date && arr[idx+1] != undefined && date < arr[idx+1].start_date) {
                season = itm.season;
                return false;
            }
        });
        return season;
    }
}

getSeason.prototype.defaults = { // start dates, (month/date)
    spring : '03/01',
    summer : '05/20',
    fall   : '08/04',
    winter : '10/10'
}
```

You initialize a new season checker with `new`, like this :

```
var seasonChecker = new getSeason;
```

and then use it to check the season, you can pass a valid string or a date object :

```
seasonChecker( '03/20/14' );                            // returns "spring"
seasonChecker( '03-20-14' );                            // returns "spring"
seasonChecker( new Date('Thu Mar 20 2014 00:00:00') );  // returns "spring"
seasonChecker( new Date(1395270000000) );               // returns "spring"
```

You can get the default dates with :

```
seasonChecker('getDefaults');
```

or set the default dates for an instance at any time with :

```
seasonChecker('setDefaults', {
    spring : '02/21',
    summer : '03/22',
    fall   : '06/04',
    winter : '11/01'
});
```

Here's a demonstration

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FqVKG/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Luckily my client was happy with simply doing it by month, but I will definitely use this if anything similar comes up again.